# Subtotal calculates from original product price, disregards applied per product discounts

Tags: commerce

This seems like a known issue but I actually didn't find a solution for this anywhere.

In commerce, if I apply a discount/pricing rule to a certain product, add it to cart, and go to checkout, table would say eg

```
Product - 120$ (discounted from original 200$)
Subtotal - 200$
```

The subtotal is taken from the original product price and doesn't include the applied discount. It would be a lesser problem if that was just display issue. But the tax is then actually calculated from the subtotal, making the order total wrong

Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is now almost 2 years old, I assume this "discount" that they were dealing with was an older version of commerce_discount. The newest version doesn't have any kind of subtotaling problems because it affectively utilizes the price calculation system for discounting.

Comment: Still the subtotal shows the original price, not the discounted price, where as the line item shows the discounted price. So the subtotal is simply wrong.